# How to format date in meteor template

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js

I need to display a date from database in the  format 'mm-dd-yyyy'. As its saved in ISO format in `mongodb` how can I convert it in the template ? 
Here is my code.

```
       Template.templatename.vname = function () {      
        return Posts.find(); 
        }
```

And in template

```
{{#each vname}}
    {{ date }} 
{{/each}}
```

Now its getting displayed like `Tue Feb 04 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)`

I need to show it as `mm-dd-yyyy`

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You may want to create a global helper like:

```js
Template.registerHelper('formatDate', function(date) {
  return moment(date).format('MM-DD-YYYY');
});
```

Then you can use it like:

```
{{#each vname}}
  {{formatDate date}}
{{/each}}
```

This solution depends on [moment](https://atmospherejs.com/momentjs/moment) which is a handy date manipulation library. If you prefer to produce the string without using moment, there are a number of answers for this including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript).

Comment: If you want to set a custom format for the date in each template like I did, you can do something like this  `Template.registerHelper('timeFormat', function(date, format) {
  return moment(date).format(format);
});` and then in the template: `{{timeFormat datetime "MM.DD / H:mm"}}`

Answer (score 6):

moment is a greet lib

```
meteor add momentjs:moment
```

use moment in helper

```
Template.home.helpers({
    momentFormate: function(time) {

        if ((moment().unix() - moment(time).unix()) < 3600) {
            return moment(time).fromNow();
        } else {
            return moment(time).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm");
        }
    },

    })
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that works in Meteor without any dependency on another package:

```
// global helper
Template.registerHelper('formatDate', function(date) {
    return monthNames[date.getMonth()] + " " + date.getDate() + ", " + date.getFullYear();
});
```

This will return a date string formatted as "December 11, 2015". Move around `getMonth()`, `getDate()` and `getFullYear()` for your preferred format. For more formatting options, check out other methods of [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object.