# Meteor : Apply function to a value

Tags: javascript, mongodb, date, meteor

I'm just starting learning Meteor with the official tutorial (https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/templates).

I want to use the "createdAt" value that we have on the database. Since this value is an instance of Date, I want to print the day of insert using the getDay() function of the Date class.

My question : how to do so :p I mean, can we do it directly on the html file or must we use smth like a function in our .js ?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22087907/how-to-format-date-in-meteor-template) answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write a helper function for the template in the js file with some parameters and then call it in the html template `{{helperName parameter}}`

Comment: Thank! Your answer and the example of @David_Weldon make me understand a little more about Meteor.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly use momentJs as you library.Its very awesome lib for your project

link : http://momentjs.com/