# How to change format of date in Meteor/MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, date, meteor, format

my date got the format like this... 
Wed Sep 09 2015 11:43:40 GMT+0200 (CEST)

This is the way I insert the data into the mongodb...

```
Tasks.insert({
        text: text,
        gerätename: gerätenummer,
        createdAt: new Date() // current time
 });
```

But now I want only a the date format like day/month/year and time in the frontend.

What I have to change in the following code that it will work.

```
Template.body.helpers({
    tasks: function () {
      // Show newest tasks at the top
      return Tasks.find({}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}});
    }
 });

<template name="task">
    <li class="{{#if checked}}checked{{/if}}">
        <button class="delete">&times;</button>
        <input type="checkbox" checked="{{checked}}" class="toggle-checked" />
        <span class="text">{{text}}</span>
        <span class="text">{{gerätename}}</span>
        <span clas="text">{{createdAt}}</span>
    </li>
</template>
```

Thank you!

Comment: this is not going to help me regarding to my problem

Comment: You need to create a template helper to format the date. Go `Template.task.helpers({formatDate: function (date) { /* insert date formatting code from the linked question */ }})` and then replace `{{createdAt}}` with `{{formatDate createdAt}}`. I'd post this as an answer but the question was (IMO incorrectly) closed.

Comment: I agree this is a duplicate, but a meteor-specific answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22087907/how-to-format-date-in-meteor-template).